# Intellij can not locate some classes - Play SBT. Intellij bug?

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I have a few import statements in my project that are displayed in RED. Intellij shows 'Cannot resolve symbol' errors, and I am not able to autocomplete these classes or their methods. However, when I run my project it runs perfectly fine. This is strange so much so, that lets say I have an import statement

```
import org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity
```

It cannot resolve the 'Velocity' class, even though when I do a ctrl+b selecting the 'app' package, it clearly shows the Velocity class:

[image: 'Velocity' class exists inside 'app']

I am lost in this and I am struggling to code like this. Any help will be appreciated.

Best Regards.

**EDIT**: In my project, some of the dependencies are also not resolved, although I refreshed my project multiple times. The exact same dependencies are resolved in my colleague's system, who is using the same code-branch and environment as me.

[image: Dependencies not resolved]

I can see that the unresolved dependencies lie inside the play.sbt package, but are still not resolved. Is there a compatibility issue between Intellij("15.0.2") and SBT("0.13.8" mentioned in build.properties of my app)?

Comment: Which version are you using? I face the same problem with the latest EAP, but only with 'scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext'. Two coworkers had similar problems (though with different classes/packages) and only a complete wipe of the project helped.

Comment: I use intellij 15.0.2, Scala 2.11.7. I wonder why the same works for my colleague. There's either something extremely subtle I am missing, or there's a bug with intellij. The webapp runs perfectly fine, which hints that the likelihood of the latter is higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reimport project using option 'Import project from external model' and choose 'sbt'. In next window choose options like 'use auto-import' and download 'sources for SBT and plugins'.

Comment: Thanks. The options were chosen previously as well. But this time, I just re-imported the project as SBT from the directory it was located and it surprisingly worked. Still not sure what went wrong the previous time.